# is it possible to run some program in background for iphone

Tags: iphone

is it possible to run some program in background for iphone even if your app is closed by user??

i just want to know any idea any trick to do that

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's Task Completion for times when you want to keep running for up to 10 minutes after your app is switched out. After 10 minutes, the OS kills the app if it hasn't completed the tasks by then.

There's also background audio, location-based, and voip apps that are allowed to run in the background, but if you abuse them, Apple is likely to reject your app for violating the spirit of the law.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the new iOS 4 update.

Here's the part of the docs that deals with it: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html